# pandas: shift(1) all values in group, except first one (in each group) which should be 0

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3, (10,2)), columns=['a','b']).sort_values(['a'])
```

Now I'd like to replace all values in each group by the previous value in that group, except for the first value in each group which I would like to replace by 0.

This won't do:

```
df.groupby("a", sort = False).transform(lambda g: g.shift(1).fillna(0))
```

because I only want to replace the *first* `np.nan`  (*in each group*) by 0

Comment: it doesn't look like that your foo group is achieving what you're looking for. can you post the expected output for your sample df?

Comment: @Peyman: you are right the `apply` solution was not doing what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
s=df.groupby("a", sort = False).b.shift()

s
Out[913]: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    NaN
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    1.0
9    2.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
idx=s.groupby(df.a).head(1).index
s.loc[idx]=0
```

Comment: not because only the first occurrence of `np.nan` within each group should be replaced by 0.